# Passing a variable from a function to be acessible in other function [Python]

Tags: python, kivy

I'm recently new in the python world, and I'm struggling with one problem...

I'm doing an app that connects to a database in the raspberry pi (which is always changing its ip, and android phones can't solve its hostname, that's why I need to specify the address).

I'm currently using Python 3.9 and Kivy 2.0.0.

I want that those 2 variables (`mydb` and `mycursor`) inside the `variavel` function to be accessible inside the other functions... Is there any way for me to do this?

**Main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import mysql.connector

class MainWidget2(BoxLayout):

    server_connect = StringProperty("not_connected.png")
    debug_net = StringProperty()
    hosts = StringProperty()
    input_text = StringProperty()
    def variavel(self, widget):
        self.hosts= widget.text
        widget.text = ""
        try:
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=str(self.hosts), user="client", passwd="", database="skye_pap")
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            self.server_connect = 'connected.png'
        except Exception as a:
            self.debug_net = str(a)
            self.server_connect = 'not_connected.png'

    def frente(self):
        try:
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=str(self.hosts), user="client", passwd="afonso11", database="skye_pap")
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET motor=1')
            mydb.commit()
        except Exception as b:
            
            pass
    def tras(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=str(self.ids["input"].text), user="client", passwd="afonso11", database="skye_pap")
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        try:
            mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET motor=-1')
            mydb.commit()
        except Exception as b:
            pass
    def esq(self):
        try:
            self.mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET servo=1')
            self.mydb.commit()
        except Exception as b:
            pass
    def dir(self):
        try:
            self.mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET servo=2')
            self.mydb.commit()
        except Exception as b:
            pass
    def meio(self):
        try:
            self.mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET servo=0')
            self.mydb.commit()
        except Exception as b:
            pass
    def meio_motor(self):
        try:
            self.mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET motor=0')
            self.mydb.commit()
        except Exception as b:
            pass
    def lights_on(self, onemore, state):
        if state == "down":
            print("on")
            try:
                self.mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET luz=1')
                self.mydb.commit()
            except Exception as z:
                pass
        else:
            print("off")
            try:
                self.mycursor.execute('UPDATE car_controll SET luz=0')
                self.mydb.commit()
            except Exception as z:
                pass
        

class skye(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = "logoapp.png"

skye().run()
```

**skye.kv**

```
MainWidget2:

<MainWidget2>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:3
        GridLayout:#botoes esquerda
            padding: ("50dp","30px","0px","0px")
            pos: self.parent.pos
            cols: 3
            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
                    
            Button:
                text: "B1"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "100dp", "100dp"
                background_normal: 'desligado.png'
                background_down: 'ligado2.png'
                on_press: root.frente()
                on_release: root.meio_motor()

            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0

            Button:
                text: "B2"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
        
            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
                
            Button:
                text: "B3"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0


            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
                
            Button:
                text: "B4"
                size_hint: None,None
                on_press: root.tras()
                on_release: root.meio_motor()
                size: "100dp", "100dp"
                background_normal: 'desligado.png'
                background_down: 'ligado2.png'

            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        
            Image:
                source: root.server_connect
                size_hint: .8, .8
                id:server_status
            FloatLayout:
                ToggleButton:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    id: luzes_toggle
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "100dp", "100dp"
                    background_normal: 'luz_desligada.png'
                    background_down: 'luz_ligada.png'
                    on_state: root.lights_on(self, self.state)
                
            Label:
                text: root.debug_net
            TextInput:
                id: input
                multiline: False
                on_text_validate: root.variavel(self)
                text: root.input_text
            Label:
                text: root.hosts
            Button:
                text:"Falar"
            Label:
                text: "Luzes:"
            
        GridLayout:#botoes direita
            cols: 3
            padding: ("0dp","30px","50px","0px")
            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
                
                    
            Button:
                text: "B1"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0

            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0

            Button:
                text: "B2"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "100dp", "100dp"
                background_normal: 'desligado.png'
                background_down: 'ligado2.png'
                on_press: root.esq()
                on_release: root.meio()
        
            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
                
            Button:
                text: "B3"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "100dp", "100dp"
                background_normal: 'desligado.png'
                background_down: 'ligado2.png'
                on_press: root.dir()
                on_release: root.meio()

            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
                
            Button:
                text: "B4"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
                
            Button:
                text: "0"
                size_hint: None,None
                size: "70dp", "70dp"
                disabled: True
                opacity: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `self.` before every variable which you want to be accessible from every `method` in the `object`.

For example make every `mydb` variable to `self.mydb` ,and `mycursor` to `self.mycursor`.

Answer (score 0):

To promote method-scoped variables to be available to other class methods, add them to `self`:

```
self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(...[stuff]...)
self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
```

then replace all references to `mydb` with `self.mydb` and `mycursor` with `self.mycursor`.  Those variables will be accessible from other methods of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Create class variables inside the class Mainwidget2 - lets name them: class_my_db, class_my_cursor.

```
class MainWidget2(BoxLayout):

server_connect = StringProperty("not_connected.png")
debug_net = StringProperty()
hosts = StringProperty()
input_text = StringProperty()
class_my_db = '' //New Class Variable to hold my_db
class_my_cursor = '' //New Class Variable to hold my_cursor
```

Now you can set the class variables their value after reading through mysql.

```
def variavel(self, widget):
    self.hosts= widget.text
    widget.text = ""
    try:
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=str(self.hosts), user="client", passwd="", database="skye_pap")
        self.class_my_db = mydb //assigning mydb to the class variable
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        self.class_my_cursor = mycursor //assigning mydb to the class variable
        self.server_connect = 'connected.png'
    except Exception as a:
        self.debug_net = str(a)
        self.server_connect = 'not_connected.png'
```

Now you can access the class variables in all other functions using *self* operator. `self.class_my_db` and `self.class_my_cursor` would suffice that.

Comment: ok, got it. Thats rlly useful, but i think the other methods are more simple and less confuse, you r creating variables unnecessarily. But Thanks!! 1+ thing learned today